# Index tombstones size configuration is unable to be set as it's unrecognised in elasticsearch 5.4.0

Tags: elasticsearch

I have tried to configure property  **cluster.indices.tombstones.size** but it is giving exception as follows:

```
[2018-07-23T09:39:29,268][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [master-1] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown setting [cluster.indices.tombstones.size] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:127) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.0.jar:5.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:114) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.0.jar:5.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:67) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.0.jar:5.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:122) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.0.jar:5.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:88) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.0.jar:5.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:91) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.0.jar:5.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:84) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.0.jar:5.4.0]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown setting [cluster.indices.tombstones.size] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings
        at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:293) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.0.jar:5.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:256) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.0.jar:5.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.SettingsModule.<init>(SettingsModule.java:139) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.0.jar:5.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:342) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.0.jar:5.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:242) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.0.jar:5.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$6.<init>(Bootstrap.java:242) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.0.jar:5.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:242) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.0.jar:5.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:360) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.0.jar:5.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:123) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.0.jar:5.4.0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I have taken backup of indexes and going to import that indexes again then it shows error as dangling index can not be imported.

After research we found that deleted indexes are stored in tombstones so we tried to reduce size of tombstones. Unfortunately this property not working with **elastic 5.4.0** but some articles suggesting that was fixed in higher versions.

**Workaround:**

Index tombstones prevent nodes that are not part of the cluster when a delete occurs from joining the cluster and re importing the index as though the delete was never issued. To keep the cluster state from growing huge we only keep the last **cluster.indices.tombstones.size** deletes, which **defaults to 500**.

So I have **created dummy indexes and deleted that so to reach the size upto 500** , after that it removes older indexes and able to import older indexes.

**Kibana Query to get all deleted indexes present in tombstones:**

```
GET /_cluster/state?filter_path=**.tombstones&pretty=true
```